# What is the best way to insert a line before a certain pattern in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, pattern-matching

This is an apache2 config file for 000-site.conf.
It has config like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node1 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node2 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on  ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node3 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node4 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node5 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node6 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node7 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>
```

What I want to do is insert a new BalancerMember with `#` before the line `ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests`. I will use shell script to do this.

So it should look like:
 `#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60`

Also, I will use IP address as variable and node number too.

I will write the code to increase node number. I have tried using sed by giving a line number and doing it, but I want it to be dynamic not static.

I need a best practice for this solution. Please help me with your ideas and best practices.

Comment: Please always try to show your effort in your post which you have made in order to solve your problem, as we all are here for learning. This is very common question in SO `awk` and `sed` forums so try to use search functionality of SO too and learn from there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will keep in mind.

Comment: @Ashutosh you have 2 answers that work. Please put a closure to your question by marking one of the questions as answered.

Comment: wrt `I will write the code to increase node number.` - if you're considering calling the awk script that does this once repeatedly in a shell loop to do it multiple times, that's probably completely unnecessary and generally a bad idea.

Comment: Then what do you suggest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v s1='"' '
/ProxySet lbmethod=requests/{
  print ORS "#BalancerMember " s1 "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" s1 " route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60"  ORS $0
  next
}
1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

So, From @RavinderSingh13's answer I modified it a bit and got the exact solution that I wanted.

```
#!/bin/bash
your_ip='10.6.0.8'
ip="$your_ip";no="8"; awk -v line="#BalancerMember \"ajp://${ip}:8009\" route=node${no} loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60" '
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{
print "             " line ORS $0
next
}
1' /tmp/000-site.conf > /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp && mv /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp /tmp/000-site.conf
```

This script takes shell variable and uses it inside the awk variable.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand the use of s1 and  ORS.
Also, I just want to print the new line inserted, not the whole config.

Comment: @Ashutosh, `s1` is awk variable which has `"` in it and `ORS` is awk out of the box variable which has new line in it. I didn't get you want to insert a NEW LINE when a match of a string found(I mean a match found for a line)?

Comment: I know that you are storing `"` in s1 variable, the question is why, is it used for escaping? I want to insert a NEW LINE and also print it. As of now it is inserting the line and printing the whole config file.

Comment: @Ashutosh, in `awk` variables are not like shell as well as escaping is not required inside `awk` code so have put in its variable. check my edit now ?

Comment: It is not making any changes in the file, it is just printing it. I think you got me wrong here. After I run the script, the 000-site.conf must have a line before the pattern. And it should also display only the single line that was appended.

Comment: Also, Varibles are not working when I use $variable_name instead of IP and node no.

Comment: @Ashutosh, why you are not telling all your requirements on single time, using variables was not in your original question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it will take variable as it does in shell.

Comment: @Ashutosh, use like `awk -v var="$shell_variable" ........` don't use `$var` inside `awk` code it is having different meaning in awk.

Comment: But in this script already s1 is used, how to use multiple variables?

Comment: @Ashutosh, simple give some other names to variables like `-v s2 -v s3` etc

Comment: Okay Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try `sed`, here's an example:

```
sed 's_ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests_#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=requests_g' 000-site.conf
```

**Result**

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node1 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node2 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on  ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node3 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node4 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node5 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node6 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                 BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node7 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
                #BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
        ProxySet lbmethod=requests
        </Proxy>
```

**Explanation**

`sed` uses substitution in quotation `'s_old-string_new-string_g'` on the file 000-site.conf.

Old string is `ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests`

It is substituted by `#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=requests`. The `\n\t\t` asks sed to introduce a new line and 2 tabs followed by the old string.

**Writing back to the file**

You can write commands to make a backup file of 000-site.conf and write the new text containing the `#BalancerMember...` into 000-site.conf like this:

```
cp 000-site.conf 000-site.conf.orig

sed 's_ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests_#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=requests_g' 000-site.conf.orig > 000-site.conf
```

**Resources**

https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-sed

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

**EDIT**

If you are using the `sed` command in a shell, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=10.0.0.1
no=11

cp 000-site.conf 000-site.conf.orig

sed 's_ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests_#BalancerMember "ajp://'$a':8009" route=node'$no' loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=requests_g' 000-site.conf.orig > 000-site.conf
```

Comment: great insight, I liked the idea of taking backup of the file, but the problem is when I use variable for getting the IP  and node no it doesn't work. Have a look at my code: `sed 's_ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests_#BalancerMember "ajp://$a:8009" route=node$no loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=reqeusts_g' 000-site.conf`

Comment: I've added a shell script example. Note `..."ajp://'$a':8009...` and `...node'$no'...`. I am putting a `'` just before and after the variables so as to inject the variables as a part of sed's continuation.

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in your code's last line requests.

Comment: Are you talking about the spelling of `requests`? That's been updated.

Comment: It works the first time, but after that when I change the variable values in the script it doesn't work. My script: `#!/bin/bash 
a=10.0.1.1 
no=12 

cp /tmp/000-site.conf /tmp/000-site.conf.orig 

sed 's_ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests_#BalancerMember "ajp://'$a':8009" route=node'$no' loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60\n\t\tProxySet lbmethod=requests_g' /tmp/000-site.conf.orig > /tmp/000- site.conf`

Comment: The reason it doesn’t work the 2nd time is that you are overwriting the original file during each run. Keep your original file as-is. Remove the line with cp. Instead, just make a copy of the original file **outside** of your script. That’s as far as I’m willing to help you. We both have provided you with ample instructions so that you can help yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all your Help!

Comment: I'm unable to do this the second time, as you said cp the file outside the script, this will be difficult as the configuration changes from time to time.

Comment: Create a new question and someone might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
ip='myip://1.2.3.4:1234' n='8'

sed -ri ':a;h;n;/ProxySet/{x;s@(\S.*").*(".*node)[0-9]*@#\1'$ip'\2'$n'@p;x};ba' file
```

Delay printing every line (except the first) and store the previous line in the hold space (HS). If the current line contains `ProxySet` amend the previous lines copy in HS to the required result and print it first.

N.B. Use `@` as the delimiter in the substitution command to avoid having to quote the `/`'s

Comment: This looks complicated. Can you help me with the @zedfoxus's answer? The only thing missing is in his answer is when I run the script 2nd time nothing happens.